# I can't import file in dbeaver nor postgreSQL

Tags: dbeaver

Everytime i tried to import csv files, it always ended up like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrQmb.jpg)
Select input file (not responding)????
What's wrong with this ??

I've already tried to restart my laptop, update my windows, end task app, but all of them have led to nothing

Comment: Don't use DBeaver, use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Comment: But the message states that the process is busy with smth, and there is a wait option. What if just select wait option and wait?

Comment: I have tried the wait option tho, still didn't work

Comment: Maybe the file you are trying to load is very big and will take a very long time.  Maybe it is very very big and will take a very very long time.  Maybe it is very very very big and will take a very very very long time.  How can anyone know based on the information provided?

Comment: No, I haven't been given a chance to select a file, it happened before I clicked on any file. So it wasn't bcs the size